# How to move interchangeably between the VS2015 and Ionic CLI

Tags: cordova, npm, ionic-framework, bower, visual-studio-cordova

When [Tools for Apache Cordova in Visual Studio 2015 RC](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2015/05/01/tools-for-apache-cordova-in-visual-studio-2015-rc.aspx) was released, the claim was that there was compatibility with “Stock” Cordova Projects.

I would like to be able to move interchangeably between the IDE and command line tools.

I have Visual Studio 2015 with Visual Studio for Apache Cordova Tools (recently updated via Tools -> Updates and Extensions)

I have recently re-installed Node.js, npm and Ionic as per [getting started with Ionic](http://ionicframework.com/getting-started/)

To get my project set up for both the IDE and the CLI, I did the following:

1. In VS2015 right-clicked solution -> Add -> New project -> Javascript -> Ionic Tabs App
2. Run using Ripple - success.
3. In a command line `ionic start MyApp` to create an ionic project using the Ionic CLI
4. Run MyApp using `ionic serve` - success
5. Copied the contents of the MyApp folder into the folder created in step 1 keeping files with the same name (so that I can compare them later - they are only related to the app and the copied index.html is renamed so the ionic version will not run).
6. Run in Ripple - success
7. Open command window in folder created in step 1 - `ionic serve` - success
8. I noticed that I was getting the following message in the Output Window when viewing Task Runner Explorer: `'gulp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
   operable program or batch file` so I ran `npm install -g gulp` and that message no longer appears

However, when I look at the project in VS2015, the Bower dependencies show a warning that they are not installed

[image: ionic - not installed]

Also I get errors in the output window from Bower/NPM:

> Error - Cannot load global packages. System.AggregateException: One or
>   more errors occurred. --->
>   Microsoft.NodejsTools.Npm.PackageJsonException: Error reading
>   package.json at
>   'C:\Users\Colin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\package.json':
>   Error reading package.json. The file may be parseable JSON but may
>   contain objects with duplicate properties.

I don't know if these might be related to my re-install of Node and npm rather than just trying to combine the two templates, but how do I go about fixing these issues?

**EDIT**
Looks like the error in the `graceful-fs\package.json` is down to a [bug in npm](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/9965)